# "The best and brigthest is..." or "the best and the brightest are..."?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number

I asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253814/the-best-and-brightest-is-leaving-stackoverflow-are-you-aware-of-it) on another StackExchange site, and used "the best and brightest..." as a singular "noun"/expression.

However, one of the people that commented used "the best and the brightest..." as a plural, and with two "the" articles.

Who is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are, depending on what you want to say:

> The [best and brightest] (*student*) **is** John.

**or**

> The [best and brightest] (*student**s***) **are** John and Mary.

**or**

> [The best] (*student*) and [the brightest] (*student*) **are** John and Mary respectively.

**or even**

> [The best] (*students*) and [the brightest] (*students*) **are** the hardest working and the smartest.

In your example, since you were talking about multiple people, you should have said, "The best and the brightest are..."

As for the question in your comment:

> lets say I meant just "idiomatic" usage: if I want to say something like "smartest, most valuable people in a group",

You are talking about *people*, that is *plural*, you use the *plural*. It does not get simpler than that, I'm afraid :)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for answer, but lets say I meant just "idiomatic" usage: if I want to say something like "smartest, most valuable people in a group", should I say "the best and brightest" (singular, like in "the blind", "the poor") or "the best and the brightest" (plural)? Or maybe even "the best and brightest" (without second "the") is also plural?

Comment: @starsplusplus: thank you for the edit, I had not realized the asker of that question was the same as here :)

Comment: @VividD: without the second _the_, it tends to be read as a whole. That can still be singular or plural, depending on what you mean. Do you mean **one** person leaves, or do you mean **several** people leave? You can **not** use the singular to _mean_ plural in this way :)

Comment: Ok, @oerkelens, that clarifies some dilemmas, thanks!

Comment: @VividD You might also find [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8521/what-does-the-adjective-mean/16396#16396) helpful, though it doesn't point out the point oerkelens just made.

Comment: @VividD Actually [Jay's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/8537) to the same question probably addresses what you were saying better than mine did.

Comment: The second "the", before brightest, can always be removed (but might need a pause if referring to different students "The best, and brightest, respectively, are:...) and is unrelated to singular/plural usage.

Comment: @starsplusplus , yes, thanks, I meant the usage that Jay described as" without noun (implied or explicit)" in his answer

Comment: @msam I think you can do that when there's a noun implied, but it's more debateable when there isn't. For a start, you might be talking about two different groups. "The unemployed and the less fortunate..." is the union of those two sets, but "the unemployed and less fortunate" is the intersection.

Comment: @starsplusplus previous comment was meant at this particular example not as a general rule, in your example it **does** make a difference and the version with 2 "the"s requires a plural, since we're now talking about 2 groups. The version with 1 "the" can still take both plural and singular.

Comment: @msam Ah right. Your use of "always" made me think you were talking about this as a general rule.